# Formatting a long system.out.print containing many strings & integers

Tags: java

Let's say you have the following:

```
String cake = "whatever";
int cakeNumber = 509;
String whyNot = "another string";
double number = 1;

system.out.println("I like "+ cake +" and I eat " + cakeNumber + " blah blah     prolonging this string because " + whyNot + " and so on " + number + ".");
```

So, that doesn't make much sense, and it doesn't have to, because it's just an example. My question is this, given multiple strings and variables with a 'plus' between them, it looks like a mess. Isn't there a way to format this println or perhaps tidy it up a little by reducing the amount of pluses?

Comment: how about `System.out.format`?

Comment: If you want it to look nice, just put some newlines every so often to spread out the pluses. I do this and I never get annoyed (though I have extreme OCD when it comes to code...).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [`java.lang.StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

```
System.out.println(new StringBuilder("I like")
                   .append(cake)
                   .append(" and I eat ")
                   .append(cakeNumber)
                   .append(" blah blah     prolonging this string because ")
                   .append(whyNot)
                   .append(" and so on ")
                   .append(number)
                   .append(".")
                   .toString());
```

---

## [`java.text.MessageFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html)

```
System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("I like {0} and I eat {1} blah blah    prolonging this string because {2} and so on {3}.",
                   cake, cakeNumber, whyNot, number));
```

I kind of like it with a static import, like this:

```
import static java.text.MessageFormat.format;

System.out.println(format("I like {0} and I eat {1} blah blah    prolonging this string because {2} and so on {3}.",
                   cake, cakeNumber, whyNot, number));
```

---

## [`java.util.Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) (also known as [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-))

```
System.out.printf("I like %s and I eat %d blah blah    prolonging this string because %s and so on %f.%n",
                  cake, cakeNumber, whyNot, number);
```

You have lots of syntactic choice at your disposal here (Just to list some, there is probably more):

```
System.out.format(...)
System.out.printf(...)
System.out.print(String.format(...)) // you will need to include the line break in the format
System.out.println(String.format(...)) // line break will be caused by println()
import static java.lang.String.format;
System.out.print(format(...))
System.out.println(format(...))
System.out.println(new Formatter().format(...))
```

`%n` represents the system's specific line break character. It is required because `printf` does not insert a line break after the operation automatically.

---

## Multiline string concatenation

```
System.out.println("I like " + cake + " and I eat " +
                   cakeNumber + " blah blah    prolonging this string because" +
                   whyNot + " and so on " + number + ".");
```

Comment: We use `MessageFormat` a lot, and make the format string `I like {0} and I eat {1} blah blah`etc. a loaded _resource_. That way you can just add another resource to translate into another language. That's also why the arg numbering `{1} stuff {0}` is superior to printf `%s`, because those words might appear in a different order in another language, but you don't have to re-arrange the variable parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Try `printf`

For example, you could write

```
System.out.printf("I like %s and I eat %d blah blah     prolonging this string because %s and so on %0.f.\n", cake, cakenumber, whyNot, number);
```

Also note that many IDEs (like Eclipse) will allow you to easily span strings across many lines. But the advantage of `printf` is that you separate the string from the variables, and also allows for better control over the display of numbers. For example, notice the `%.0f`. In general you can specify how much space the value should take up including padding and how many decimal places to use.

Comment: This was exactly what I was searching for! Thanks a ton!

Comment: Hold on, is it possible to change the letters %s and %d?

Comment: No, it's not. Consult the documentation for `java.util.Formatter` for more information on what's possibly and what these escape sequences mean.

Comment: @LawrenceLelo Going back to the days of C, at runtime you could not determine the type of the arguments to the printf function (C lacks method overloading). To get around this, the letter after the % specifies the type of the argument. %s means string, %d means intrger, and %f means floating point number. This should always match the type of the corresponding variable.

Answer (score 0):

One option, if you'd like to cut down on lines and plusses, you could break it up into a number of `System.out.print`'s:

```
System.out.print("I like "+ cake); 
System.out.print(" and I eat " + cakeNumber);
System.out.print(" blah blah     prolonging this string because ");
System.out.println(whyNot + " and so on " + number + ".");
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you can try:

```
int age = 24;
double salary = 4500.25;
String name = "Marcelo";
String message = "Hi, my name is %s and I'm %d years old and I earn %f.";

System.out.println(String.format(message,name,age,salary));
```

Remember that `String.format` uses the default locale :)

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) or [`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

```
String cake = "whatever";
int cakeNumber = 509;
String whyNot = "another string";
double number = 1;

System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("{0}..{1}..{2}..", cake, cakeNumber, ..));
```

Comment: This may be simplified to `printf()`.

Comment: yes, `printf` is more suitable for primitive type formatting. so you have to care about is it `%s` or `%d`

Answer (score 0):

Some example output for your consideration.

```
$ javac Foo.java
$ java Foo

--- Original ---
I like whatever and I eat 509 blah blah     prolonging this string because another string and so on 1.0.

--- whitespace is your friend---
I like whatever and I eat 509 blah blah     prolonging this string because another string and so on 1.0.

--- Also, look into printf ---
I like "whatever" and I eat 00509 blah blah     prolonging this string because "another string" and so on  1.00
```

When you start wanting to do any kind of non-default formatting to parameters (zero padding, space filling, only showing 2 digits on your floting point values and so on), printf becomes really helpful.

### Foo.java

```
public class Foo {
   public static void main( String args[] ) {
      String cake = "whatever";
      int cakeNumber = 509;
      String whyNot = "another string";
      double number = 1;

      System.out.println("\n--- Original ---");
      System.out.println("I like "+ cake +" and I eat " + cakeNumber + " blah blah     prolonging this string because " + whyNot + " and so on " + number + ".");

      System.out.println("\n--- whitespace is your friend---");
      System.out.println("I like "+ cake 
         +" and I eat " + cakeNumber 
         + " blah blah     prolonging this string because " 
         + whyNot + " and so on " 
         + number + ".");


      System.out.println("\n--- Also, look into printf ---");
      //  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html
      System.out.printf("I like \"%s\" and I eat %05d blah blah"
         +"     prolonging this string because \"%s\" and so on %5.02f\n" 
         , cake 
         , cakeNumber 
         , whyNot
         , number );
   }

}
```